# Excel VBA count cells until a date is found

Tags: excel, sorting, count, vba

I've got an amount of data copied from a table in a .pdf that when pasted into excel puts it all into one column. There are actually multiple pages each with it's own table (the data is one continuous long table split over multiple pages more accurately) and at the top of each page is a series of lines that I'm not interested in (the same unwanted data is at the top of each page). What I am interested in is re-sorting the data under the headers as it is in the table on the original .pdf document, removing the headers in the process. The data as it has been pasted into one column essentially is a list of items in plain text for x rows, followed by a list of start dates for x rows, and then a list of end dates for x rows, repeated every page.

I've figured out how to count the number of lines I don't want by getting a macro to look for the first piece of data I'm interested in ("AAAA") starting at cell (B2);

```
Cells(2, 2).Select

    For i = 1 To 50
    If ActiveCell = "AAAA" Then
        Exit For
    End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next i

Cells(2, 3) = i

    If i = 51 Then
        Range("B3") = "Cannot find data"
    End If
```

Which starts a search at cell (B2) looking downwards until it finds "AAAA" it then prints how many rows it has moved downwards to find it in cell (C2).

I now wish to be able to start at the cell it has just found [(B34) in this case] and count downwards until it finds the first cell containing a date.

Ultimately I'll need to then count down the same number of cells to find the associated end date and print them all in one row, continuing for the entire column of data.

If anybody could help me with being able to start at the first cell "AAAA" and then count downwards until a date is found, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code starts in cell `A1` and searches downward until it finds a cell containing a date value. The code only searches until it reaches the last record in the first column (to avoid searching all the way down to the bottom of the sheet if no date is found).

```
Sub FindFirstDate()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If IsDate(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value) = True Then Exit For
    Next i
    MsgBox "The first cell with a date is " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Address
End Sub
```

In this example the address of the cell with the first date in returned in a `MsgBox`.

Answer (score 0):

My biggest challeng is to understand what you want to be true. I tryed to make a list of the things what you want.

1. You have a PDF that when paste in Excel it transform all the
   document in one column.
2. There is a header in each of the Excel pages that you want to delete.
3. After you find a header you want to find two dates, and they have the same distance from the header.

How I would do it:

```
For iCounter = 1 to Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  If Cells(iCounter,1) = "YOUR HEADER HERE" then
    For kCounter = iCounter to Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       If IsDate(Cells(kCounter,1)) = true then
           initialDate = Cells(kCounter,1)
           endDate = Cells(2*kCounter-iCounter,1)
       End if
    Next kCounter
  End if
Next iCounter
```